# Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $x^3-x>0$, then $x>-1$. Contrapositive proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $x^3-x>0$, then $x>-1$.

Proof (Contrapositive). Suppose $x \leq -1$. It follows that $x^3 \leq x \leq -1$.
Picking $x=-1$, the quantity $x^3-x=0$, otherwise it is negative.
Therefore, $x^3-x \leq 0.\hspace{1mm} \Box$

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that it's correct, but it's not necessarily rigorous enough (the required rigor is depending heavily on the context of your question though). If I wanted to be really nitpicky I'd say you didn't actually show why $x^3-x$ is negative for $x<-1$, or why $x \leq -1 \implies x^3 \leq x$ holds. The reasons are so simple that you might feel there's no need to elaborate on them; but if you're just getting the hang of proving things, it's good to be clear on every little detail.

And by the way, there's no need for treating $x=-1$ as a separate case - from $x^3 \leq x$ it immediatly follows that $x^3-x \leq 0$.

Comment: How would I show $x \leq -1 \Rightarrow x^3 \leq x$ in more detail? Would the intermediate step $x^3 \leq -x^2 \leq x$ be sufficient? Also, would $x^3 \leq -x^2 \leq x $ show that $x^3-x$ is negative for $x < -1$?

Comment: Yes, it would be sufficient to show $x^3 \leq -x^2 \leq x$ (and you can in fact reach that from $x \leq -1$ by simple algebraic manipulation). As for your other question, $x^3 \leq x$ doesn't immediately imply that $x^3-x<0$ for $x<-1$, but $x^3<x$ does, and the latter is equivalent to $x^2>1$ (keeping in mind that $x$ is still assumed to be less than $-1$), which you probably know (or again can deduce by using algebra, i.e. $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)<0$, since both of the terms on the lefthand side are negative by our assumption).